# Affine scheme on spec(A) of a ring A as the sheafification of a pre-sheave on spec(A)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

It is obvious that there is a parallel between the definition of structure sheaf of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$
versus the sheafification of a pre-sheaf.

The definition of the sheaf $\mathscr F^+$ associated to pre-sheaf $\mathscr F$ is (Hartshorne p.64):

> For any open set $U$, let $\mathscr F^+ (U)$ be the set of functions $s$ from $U$ to the union of stalks $\mathscr F_P$ of $\mathscr F$ over points $P$ of $U$ such that:
>
> 1. For each $P$ in $U$, $s(P)$ is in $\mathscr F_p$.
> 2. For each $P$ in $U$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $P$ , contained in $U$, and an element $t$ in $\mathscr F(V)$, such that for all $Q$ in $V$, the germ $t_Q$ of $t$ at $Q$ is equal to $s(Q)$.

While, in (Hartshorne p.70), the definition of the sheaf of rings $\mathscr O$ on $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is:

> For any open set $U$ of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, let $\mathscr O(U)$ be the set of functions $s$ from $U$ to the union of localizations $A_\mathscr{p}$ of $A$ at $\mathscr{p}$ such that:
>
> For each $\mathscr{p}$ in $U$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\mathscr{p}$, contained in $U$, and elements $a,f$ of $A$, such that for each $\mathscr{q}$ in $V$, $f$ not in $\mathscr{q}$, and $s(\mathscr{q}) = a/f$ .

So, is there a naturally occurring pre-sheaf on $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ (which in general is not a sheaf) that exists for any ring $A$ such that its sheafification gives exactly the structure sheaf $\mathscr O$ of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$?

Comment: Are you asking for a presheaf of rings on the topological space that underlies the spectrum of A, or a presheaf of sets on e.g., the category of affine schemes?

Comment: I'm asking for any type of presheaf on the topological space that underlies the spectrum of A: a presheaf of rings or of sets or what ever structure on it s.t the sheafification will give back the usual affine scheme we have on spec(A). 

Comment: Well it will have to be a presheaf of local rings, otherwise it won't sheafify to the structure sheaf of anything. And please make a distinction between the scheme and the structure sheaf; a scheme is a sheaf on the category of rings, whereas a structure sheaf is a sheaf on a topological space. There seems to be a misunderstanding here...

Comment: Why should it be a presheaf of local ring? You probably want the stalks to be local...

Comment: Also, the sentence "a scheme is a sheaf on the category of rings, whereas a structure sheaf is a sheaf on a topological space" looks seriously misleading to me. Both sheaves are on a topological space. As for the categories, schemes are sheaves of rings and structure sheaves are sheaves of abelian groups. Or do you mean schemes as functors, and "sheaf" in the functorial sense (Zariski sheaf)? In this case this may be correct but is still misleading, sorry...

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes" for degenerate reasons. For example, if Spec(A) is covered by two affine opens not equal to Spec(A), then it is easy to change the presheaf so that the ring of global sections is altered but nothing else, and the associated sheaf remains unchanged. Your question would be more clear if you spelled out the "obvious" parallel in more detail. 

Comment: Even more degenerately: well, $\mathcal{O}_{Spec(A)}$ is a sheaf hence... well, a presheaf.. whose sheafification remains $\mathcal{O}_{Spec(A)}$. This shows that I have probably not understood the question.

Comment: @darij #1 - hmm, possibly. I'm not an algebraic geometer, and I haven't thought about how the stalks of a sheaf of rings end up as local rings #2 - I'm thinking of a scheme as its functor of points. This is a sheaf on $Ring$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In the definition of $\mathscr O_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}$, it should be $(\exists a,f\in A)(\forall\mathfrak q\in V)\ f\notin\mathfrak q\land s(\mathfrak q)=a/f$, not $(\exists a,f\in A)(\forall\mathfrak q\in V)\ f\notin\mathfrak q\to s(\mathfrak q)=a/f$ (you could always take $f=0$).

Comment: @a-fortiori I have fixed the formula as per your suggestion. Thanks for the answer! 

Comment: @darijgrinberg I am not accusing anyone of anything but the phrase "a scheme is a sheaf on the category of rings" was clear to me (and when I first read your comment, "both sheaves are on a topological space...schemes are sheaves of rings", I at first thought you were the one making misleading claims here). I guess the way you think of schemes depends on the type of work you do. However, David Roberts' comment is definitely not misleadging for everyone.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For any open subset $U\subseteq\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ let $S_U=A\setminus\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in U}\mathfrak p$ and $\mathscr O'(U)=A[S_U^{-1}]$. It is obviously a presheaf.

Claim: For open subsets of the form $U=\mathrm{Spec}(A_f)$ with $f\in A$ we have $\mathscr O'(U)=A_f$. (This shows that the associated sheaf of $\mathscr O'$ is indeed $\mathscr O_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}$.)

Proof: Assume there is an $s\in S_U$ which does not divide $f^n$ for any $n$. The ideal $(s)$ does not meet the multiplicative set $S_f=\{1,f,f^2,\dots\}$, so it is contained in an ideal $\mathfrak q$ which is maximal with respect to this property, but it is well-known that such an ideal $\mathfrak q$ is prime. By construction, $s\in\mathfrak q\in U$, contradicting $s\in S_U$.

Applying the usual associated sheaf construction to $\mathscr O'$ seems to be what Hartshorne does when he defines $\mathscr O_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}$.

Comment: Probably this is the best definition of the structure sheaf on the specrum ... and I wonder why I haven't seen it yet :).

Comment: The mapping $U \mapsto S_U$ is a sheaf on $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, in fact a subsheaf of the constant sheaf $\underline{A}$. It is also called the "universal filter" or "generic filter" of $A$. The structure sheaf can then simply be constructed as the localization $\underline{A}[S^{-1}]$ (performed in the internal language of the topos of sheaves over $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$).

Comment: $U=\text{Spec }(A_f)$ means the set of all prime ideals in $A$ which are correspondent with the prime ideals in $A_f$. That is, the set of all prime ideals in $A$ which are disjoint $\{1, f, f^2, ...\}$.

Comment: Interesting! Hartshorne verified
(or expected readers to verify) $\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec }A}$ is a sheaf directly. 
Then proved that $\mathscr{O}(D(f))\cong A_f$. 
You did that in a reverse way.

Comment: Why "This shows that the associated sheaf of $\mathscr{O}'$ is indeed $\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec }(A)}$"? I think it suffices to show that $\mathscr{O}'_{\mathfrak{p}}=\varinjlim\limits_{\mathfrak{p}\in U}\mathscr{O}'(U)=\varinjlim\limits_{f\in A\backslash \mathfrak{p}}\mathscr{O}'(X_f)=\varinjlim\limits_{f\in A\backslash \mathfrak{p}}A_f=A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
But I cannot prove $\varinjlim\limits_{\mathfrak{p}\in U}\mathscr{O}'(U)=\varinjlim\limits_{f\in A\backslash \mathfrak{p}}\mathscr{O}'(X_f)$. Could anyone help me? Thx!